# How do you handle multiple user in queuing system?

Tags: php, system, queuing

[please click this link to show picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihW4X.png) Im having a hard time analyzing on how I will create a queuing system where there is multiple user. Let us say that there is 2 user that is using a system how will i implement it? i dont get the logic on how it will be implemented. Like if the first user will tap the next button how will I update it as well that the queue number is update with the other user

Comment: I think you need to edit your question. I don't understand what you are asking? what queuing system? Is this related to background processes? queuing the action of something when a button is pressed? What is it you're actually wanting to queue?

Comment: Depening on what you answer to my above comment, you have many methods of queuing. You could queue jobs using something like Redis, you could store jobs to run in a database, etc...

Comment: queuing system like this http://queue.codekernel.net/display

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you need to use a database such as MySQL or MariaDB.

You would store the activity of each user's session in database tables. Of course, I could give you a more specific answer if your question were more specific.

Comment: I have already made a database. this is what i meant http://queue.codekernel.net/display. So what if there are 2 users or lets say counter and and are handling the same transaction. How will i implement the next number on queue or how will i update the other user that that queue number is done if I press next button. How will i divide all those transaction to each counter